# Trying to connect RFID Reader using NFCpy

Tags: nfc

I am trying to connect my NFC reader using nfcpy.
All installations went successful, but it seems to not be able to find my NFC reader.

This is the message I get:

"
This is the 1.0.3 version of nfcpy run in Python 3.8.1
on Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
I'm now searching your system for contactless devices
DEBUG:nfc.clf.transport:using libusb-1.0.22
DEBUG:nfc.clf.transport:path matches '^(usb|)$'
I'm not trying serial devices because you haven't told me
-- add the option '--search-tty' to have me looking
-- but beware that this may break other serial devs
Sorry, but I couldn't find any contactless device
"

Does anyone know what is going wrong?